# Getting rid of "Welcome to nginx!"

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I've just setup nginx on my Ubuntu staging machince. Entering `http://192.168.1.1./index.php` works like a charm and loads the *index.php* file i've put in the `/var/www/public_html` folder.  `http://192.168.1.1` however instead shows the **Welcome to nginx!** page and not my index.php file.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 80 default;
    root /var/www/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sure that you have no other sites in sites-enabled that might be conflicting?

Comment: BTW: Weird config with rewrites and custom fastcgi_param's, are you using some kind of howto or application specific guide?

Comment: No other sites in either `sites-enabled` or `sites-available`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for try_files: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files, you probably should have something like:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php;
}
```

Take a look at the examples for Drupal, Wordpress, FastCGI, etc.

Comment: Hi cjc. I tried both to append `try_files` inside my `location /` as well as outside of it. No change

Comment: Did you use /index.php as the last argument?

Comment: Yep! `    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
`

Comment: The other suggested thing was to have "try_files $uri $uri/ @php;" and then a @php location block with your FCGI configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you still have the default site config in sites-enabled, and that it's alphabetically sorted higher than your custom config. The default config will catch any request without known host headers, and use index.html as index.

Comment: Hi Pauska. unfortunately not - deleted the default and reloaded & restarted multiple times since :(

Comment: No difference with or without the custom `fastcgi_params` inside the ` location ~ \.php`-section

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem. It was solved when I changed the folder permissions of the index.html file.

Comment: Is that a comment? Because for my eyes it isn't an answer.

Comment: I tried to make a comment, but the system said "You must have 50 reputation to comment".