# Uninstall php and nginx or fix setup

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, debian-squeeze

First off, I'm a huge linux noob - sorry... I'm trying to setup nginx with php-fpm on debian and I'm pretty sure that I've completely screwed it up.  nginx seems to be running fine because I can it it from a web browser and it load the stock "Welcome to nginx!" page.  I'm not so sure about php-fpm though.  When I try something like

```
# restart php-fpm
```

I get:

```
bash: restart: command not found
```

First off php-fpm some how got installed as php5-fpm when I do `root@server:/etc/init.d# ls`, which seems to contradict every tutorial and help doc I've read (supposed to be 'php-fpm').

I can restart it with this:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

And just enter the package name 'php5-fpm' I get this:

```
root@server:~# php5-fpm
[17-Nov-2012 23:15:36] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[17-Nov-2012 23:15:36] ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
[17-Nov-2012 23:15:36] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

The root for nginx is /usr/share/nginx/html, when I try to navigate to a .php file in there with my web browser, it tries to download the file instead of interpret it.  I would like this folder to be in my user's home directory ie: /home/administrator/www or /home/nginx/www.  I know in order to do this I need to modify nginx.conf, but I find that configuration file difficult to understand.  I suppose the fact that my .php scripts aren't being handled is my bigger problem anyways.

When I try to see what running on port 9000 (php-fpm default port) with `lsof -i :9000` it returns nothing - I guess indicating that it isn't listening.  then I head over to `vim /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` and there is no where to designate a port number.

- So should I just uninstall everything and start from scratch? If so,
- how do I clean it all up? Any suggestions for a tutorial once I'm
- ready to try again? Should I attempt to troubleshoot this mess?
- If so where should I start?

Sorry guys, I'm feeling pretty stupid and lost right now.  I'm not sure what my next steps are in trying to resolve this issue are.  I realize that this is a horrible question for this type of Q&A site, but I'd really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Perhaps, if you don't know Linux, try it with an http server that has a less-steep learning curve?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `man` saves your bacon. If you have tried `man lsof`, you'd eliminate one question.

Next, be attentive:

> another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

silently reminds you that it makes no sense to

> try to see what running on port 9000

**So should I just uninstall everything and start from scratch?**

No, if you haven't encountered any installation errors.

**how do I clean it all up?**

You haven't done anything yet to clean up as far as I can see. Configure PHP-FPM && nginx.

**Should I attempt to troubleshoot this mess?**

That's a key to a solution! Use `less /var/log/__yourlogfile__` every time you are in doubt.

**If so where should I start?**

1. `man` command, mentioned before. Use it like man service; man php-fpm.
2. lsof -U /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
3. wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
4. Use search better: [Getting rid of "Welcome to nginx!"](https://serverfault.com/questions/301708/getting-rid-of-welcome-to-nginx) fits your question
5. Read the [Debian Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch01.en.html)